# How To List JSON objects due to similar arrays?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtsWu.png)
So me and my partner are kind of confused on how we would like to display or list other names that have the same/similar values from arrays....

we would also like to try to randomize which array is being "compared"
is there a way to do that?

here's the code I have so far:

html code:

```
<body>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="message2"></div>
<div id="related"></div>
</body>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Get JSON file
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'scripts/data.json',
    success: function(data) {

        alert("hello");
        $.each(data, function(i, objects){
            $("#message").append(objects.name );
            $("#message2").append(objects.thingYouWantToDo);
        });
    },

});
 for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
{
if(objects[i].objects.thingYouWantToDo == 'Skydive')
{
 $("related").append(objects[i].objects.name);
  }
 }
});
```

json file:

```
[
{  
    "name": "Jim",
    "iveNeverSinceIGotHere": "Went to a club",
    "oneCoolPlaceIWantedCheckOut": "Cobo hall",
    "favoritePets": "Dogs",
    "favoriteColor": "Blue",
    "age": 22,
    "foreignWhereDidYouComeFrom": "I was born here",
    "school": "College for Creative Studies",
    "socialLinkFrom": "Instagram",
    "shareASocialLink": "nahxiii",
    "willingToMeetNewPeopleStrangers": "Yes"
    "thingYouWantToDo": "Skydive"
},
{
    "name": "Tommy ",
    "oneCoolPlaceIWantedCheckOut": "Maldives",
    "age": 24,
    "foreignWhereDidYouComeFrom": "China ",
    "school": "Wayne State University",
    "socialLinkFrom": "Wechat ",
    "shareASocialLink": "pillsi",
    "willingToMeetNewPeopleStrangers": "Yes",
    "thingYouWantToDo": "Skydive"
}
]
```

For now I want to list 4 to all objects that have "skydive" in "thingYouWantToDo"

any suggestions/methods/or plugins to use?
Thank you?

Comment: It's worth trying to write some code yourself first. Have a look at `lodash` - It's a library with many different methods that could help you achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `underscore.js` man, here is the link: http://underscorejs.org/

Query: (using `_.filter(list, predicate, [context])` or `_.where(list, properties)`)

```
var skydiveObjects = _.filter(objects, function(obj) { 
  return obj.thingYouWantToDo == "skydive";
});
```

or

```
var skydiveObjects = _.where(objects, {thingYouWantToDo: "skydive"});

_.map(skydiveObjects, function(obj) {
   $("related").append(obj.name);
})
```